# Mysql how to filter trough field that name is mysql keyword?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table where one of column has name "from" the same as mysql keyword.
How do I apply such query:
`select * from some_table where from = 12;`

Comment: It woule be better if you rename the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `backticks` on mysql keyword like tableName, fieldName etc.

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE `from` = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ` to show its not a reserved name :

```
select * from some_table where `from` = 12;
```

Actually I think it's a good practice to use ` for all names (columns and tables) :

I mean :

```
select * from `some_table` where `from` = 12;
```

Comment: And even a better practice: do not name columns with reserved words. So easy to name the column fromTo or something like that...

Comment: @ADASein I couldn't agree more :)

Comment: That's true but now I'm dealing with some "legacy" database and cannot do any alteration.